# Xmldoc.load giving Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a string which contains XML. I want to create an XMLdocument from this. I am using Load and LoadXMl methods like this:

```
   Dim doc As XmlDocument
            doc.LoadXml(applicationXml)
```

but they are retuning:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<gate.util.persistence.GateApplication>
  <urlList class="gate.util.persistence.CollectionPersistence">
    <localList>      
      <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
        <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/LingPipe/</urlString>
      </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
      <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
        <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/</urlString>
      </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
      <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
        <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/Stemmer_Snowball/</urlString>
      </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>     
    </localList>
    <collectionType>java.util.ArrayList</collectionType>
  </urlList>
  <application class="gate.util.persistence.SerialAnalyserControllerPersistence">
    <prList class="gate.util.persistence.CollectionPersistence">
      <localList>
        <gate.util.persistence.PRPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>setsToKeep</string>
                <null />
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationTypes</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>corpus</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>keepOriginalMarkupsAS</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>setsToRemove</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.annotdelete.AnnotationDeletePR</resourceType>
          <resourceName>Document Reset PR</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.PRPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationSetName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.tokeniser.DefaultTokeniser</resourceType>
          <resourceName>ANNIE English Tokeniser</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>tokeniserRulesURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/tokeniser/DefaultTokeniser.rules</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>transducerGrammarURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/tokeniser/postprocess.jape</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <string>UTF-8</string>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationSetName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>com.ontotext.gate.gazetteer.HashGazetteer</resourceType>
          <resourceName>TCG Gazetteer</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>listsURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>http://halo.dyndns-web.com:96/tcg/GATE/Gazetteers/MasterListsDef.def</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <string>UTF-8</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>caseSensitive</string>
                <boolean>false</boolean>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>wholeWordsOnly</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>longestMatchOnly</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationSetName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.gazetteer.DefaultGazetteer</resourceType>
          <resourceName>ANNIE Gazetteer</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>gazetteerFeatureSeparator</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>listsURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/gazetteer/lists.def</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>caseSensitive</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <string>UTF-8</string>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>outputASName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>inputASName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.splitter.SentenceSplitter</resourceType>
          <resourceName>ANNIE Sentence Splitter</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <string>UTF-8</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>gazetteerListsURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/sentenceSplitter/gazetteer/lists.def</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>transducerURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/sentenceSplitter/grammar/main.jape</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>corpus</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>outputAnnotationType</string>
                <string>Token</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>inputASName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>failOnMissingInputAnnotations</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>outputASName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>baseSentenceAnnotationType</string>
                <string>Sentence</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>baseTokenAnnotationType</string>
                <string>Token</string>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.POSTagger</resourceType>
          <resourceName>ANNIE POS Tagger</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>rulesURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/heptag/ruleset</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>lexiconURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/heptag/lexicon</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>outputASName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null />
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>inputASName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.ANNIETransducer</resourceType>
          <resourceName>ANNIE NE Transducer</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <string>UTF-8</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationAccessors</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>operators</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>grammarURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/NE/main.jape</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationSetName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationTypes</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.CollectionPersistence>
                  <localList>
                    <string>Organization</string>
                    <string>Person</string>
                    <string>Location</string>
                    <string>Date</string>
                  </localList>
                  <collectionType>java.util.ArrayList</collectionType>
                </gate.util.persistence.CollectionPersistence>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>gate.creole.orthomatcher.OrthoMatcher</resourceType>
          <resourceName>ANNIE OrthoMatcher</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>definitionFileURL</string>
                <gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
                  <urlString>$gatehome$plugins/ANNIE/resources/othomatcher/listsNM.def</urlString>
                </gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager-URLHolder>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>minimumNicknameLikelihood</string>
                <double>0.5</double>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>extLists</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>encoding</string>
                <string>UTF-8</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>caseSensitive</string>
                <boolean>false</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>highPrecisionOrgs</string>
                <boolean>false</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>personType</string>
                <string>Person</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>processUnknown</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>organizationType</string>
                <string>Organization</string>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence>
        <gate.util.persistence.PRPersistence>
          <runtimeParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>document</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationSetName</string>
                <null/>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationType</string>
                <string>Token</string>
              </entry>
              <entry>
                <string>annotationFeature</string>
                <string>string</string>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </runtimeParams>
          <resourceType>stemmer.SnowballStemmer</resourceType>
          <resourceName>Stemmer</resourceName>
          <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap>
              <entry>
                <string>language</string>
                <string>english</string>
              </entry>
            </localMap>
          </initParams>
          <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
            <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
            <localMap/>
          </features>
        </gate.util.persistence.PRPersistence>
      </localList>
      <collectionType>java.util.ArrayList</collectionType>
    </prList>
    <resourceType>gate.creole.SerialAnalyserController</resourceType>
    <resourceName>ANNIE</resourceName>
    <initParams class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
      <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
      <localMap/>
    </initParams>
    <features class="gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence">
      <mapType>gate.util.SimpleFeatureMapImpl</mapType>
      <localMap/>
    </features>
  </application>
</gate.util.persistence.GateApplication>
```

Please suggest solution to this.

Comment: `Dim doc As New XmlDocument()` maybe? Looks like `doc` has not be instantiated yet.

Comment: @JasonEvans, You rock :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `New` keyword since `XmlDocument` is a reference type:

```
  Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx#Y0  for more details.

Comment: This worked for me thank you. Since the question was for vb.net here's the vb syntax: `Dim doc As New XmlDocument`